# Как войти на web сервис через Http запрос android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Хочу сделать http запрос для получение сведений, но на сервисе установлен логин и пароль(которые я знаю). Как зайти на сервис, через какие методы передавать логин и пароль для входа?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо:

1. Открыть инструменты разработчика в браузере.
2. Открыть в них вкладку, отображающую сетевые запросы.
3. Авторизоваться в браузере.
4. Во вкладке из п.2 появится информация о запросе отправленном на сервер.
5. Повторите этот запрос программно из приложения.
6. В ответе от сервера будет, скорее всего, заголовок `Set-Cookie`. Его значение вам надо сохранить.
7. Все следующие запросы к сайту делайте, прикрепляя данные из п.6 в качестве значения для заголовка запроса с именем `Cookie` - так сервер поймёт, что запрос делаете именно вы, тот кто ранее авторизовался.

Comment: лишь так? нету никакого другого способа авторизации? каждый раз чтобы авторизовываться. Может есть метод в java, который бы выполнял данную функцию, исключая cookie

Comment: @Денис, по другому никак. Вам в любом случае надо делать запрос на сервер и после прикреплять к последующим запросам данные аутентификации. Это нужно, т.к. сервер должен у себя записать информацию о вас, сохранить временный пароль (Cookie в данном случае) и по этому паролю определять ваши права в системе.

Comment: мне нужна авторизация на веб сервис 1с, то есть мне нужно сохранять куки? а просто передать вместе с запросом не получится? это обычная авторизация на веб сервис 1ски

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "просто передать вместе с запросом"? Чтобы что-то передать, это что-то надо сначала получить и где-то хранить. Можно, конечно, и в переменной хранить, но оно может сборщиком мусора обнулиться или пропасть при перезапуске программы. Мне не очень понятно что вас смущает. Описанное в ответе - стандартная ситуация.

Comment: String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);   httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);  вот что я имел в виду

Comment: @Денис, да, по идее можно и так, если сервер умеет распознавать такой способ авторизации.